# Maintaining PHP Session Variables

Tags: php, session

I would like to maintain 3 $_Session variables after login.  My login modal submits to my index.php page and this seems to be the only place I can access the session variables I set when the user logs in.  How do I pass these variables to the next page the user visits?  I know I can use hidden inputs in forms but what if the brows the site using the menu? I would like to store a users session variables in a session include file but I have the same issue passing the values of the variables from page to page.

-Mike

Comment: Session is a global variable, it lasts for a session, why do you want to pass the variable from one page to other page, access it using $_SESSION variable

Comment: I would like to pass them to other pages to maintain a users login credentials.

Answer (score 3):

File a.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['saveme'] = 'from file A';

?>
```

File b.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['saveme']; // if you visited a.php previously, you will see "from file A"
?>
```

Setting a session variable in any file makes it available anywhere else.

Comment: I have come across this answer and have executed this exact solution and it I can not access these variables from File b.php.  I'm starting to think this is a php.ini issue maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can store you values in session on one page(index in your case as you mentioned) then later on you can get those values on any page if session in started on that page. Session store those value till same session alive.

code to set values in session:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
    <?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["xyz"] = "xyz";
    $_SESSION["abc"] = "abc";
    echo "Session variables are set.";
    ?>
```

Code to get session values:

```
<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "value of xyz is " . $_SESSION["xyz"] . ".<br>";
echo "value of abc is " . $_SESSION["abc"] . ".";
?>
```

Comment: I have come across this answer as well the only difference being that the variables are set in side of a if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  I'm starting to think this is a php.ini issue maybe?

Comment: Well i think, by default php ini file should be all set to use session, if you are putting above code in a condition as you mention in above comment, what issue you are facing..please share your code or explain in details for better understanding...

Comment: YPS,
I altered my code to reflect Hans's example below.  Please see my comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The form of your modal

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Username <input type="text" name="username" />
Password <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

Then you catch it in your `index.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    // Check if user exists and password matches

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['logintime'] = time();
    $_SESSION['something'] = 'else';
}
```

In any other page you can use the values like

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Comment: Hans,

I have altered my code to be set up like your above.  Everything woks until the last block.  When I move to another page via my main menu (contained in an include) I can access the session variables. I set up an else{echo "Session not set";} in the last block and I can see that.

Also of note, when I navigate back to index from the second page, the variables are gone.

Answer (score 0):

All who have provided answers thank you.  This overlooked detail was all on me and though I have been out of the dev game for a while I should have known better.

My hosting service by default makes all file permissions read/write only...to access session variables I changed to read/write/execute and was successful.

Again thanks!